# What is the purpose of these 2 pylons?

Tags: american-football, nfl, equipment

In the following image, you can see 3 pylons. One of them is the goal line pylon, which can be helpful in determining whether or not the ball broke the plane of the end zone on plays close to the sideline. I did not put a red arrow next to this pylon.

I put red arrows next to the other 2 pylons, whose purpose I am not sure of.

- There is a pylon very close to the goal line pylon. This pylon is larger than the goal line pylon. As you can see, on this particular play it is 3rd *and goal*, so this larger pylon cannot be any sort of first down marker. What is the purpose of this larger pylon?
- There is a pylon at the corner of the back of the end zone. I don't know why there would need to be a pylon at that location, given that it is possible for a receiver to catch a ball flying past the end zone as long as both of his feet remain inbounds. What is the purpose of this pylon?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The functional purpose of pylons such as the back pylon (portrayed on the right of the still) is to [denote the end zone](https://operations.nfl.com/the-rules/nfl-rulebook/#article-3-end-zone) (3.12.3) as [inbound lines](https://operations.nfl.com/the-rules/nfl-rulebook/#article-2-inbound-lines) (1.2.2). These are important as they play a role in [determining in and out of bounds](https://operations.nfl.com/the-rules/nfl-rulebook/#section-21-out-of-bounds-inbounds-and-inbounds-spot) (3.21.1, 3.21.2, 3.21.3) and [scoring plays](https://operations.nfl.com/the-rules/nfl-rulebook/#section-2-touchdown) (11.2.1).

The pylon portrayed on the left of the still is the [C360 pylon cam](https://www.c360live.com/pylons) which provides [video technologies](https://www.cosm.com/media/c360) on the field. The still is an ESPN Monday Night Football broadcast, which [this article](https://www.sportsbusinessjournal.com/Articles/2023/10/19/nfl-c360.aspx) calls out as one of three broadcast channels to use C360 pylon cams this season (the others being Fox and CBS).

Comment: It is not clear to me which goal line pylon - the smaller one right on the goal line or the larger one just off the goal line - is the C360 goal line pylon.

Answer (score 0):

> As you can see, on this particular play it is 3rd and goal, so this larger pylon cannot be any sort of first down marker. What is the purpose of this larger pylon?

As mentioned, it is a camera pylon.  For most plays, the pylon is placed at the first down location (line to gain) on top of a banner/arrow marking the line.

[image]

When the line to gain is the goal line, the first down marker is removed.   It looks like they place the pylon near the goal line, but away from the sideline.  That position doesn't indicate anything for gameplay, but is just another camera.

Comment: Although the smaller pylon that is right on the goal line also has a camera, making the larger pylon seemingly redundant.